# Textchanged event won't calculate correctly

Tags: c#

I have been trying to make a simple second to hour and minute converter just to practice some C#. The weird thing is as I pass 599 seconds mark, the program subtracts 60 seconds. So, 540 seconds equals 9 minutes; 599 seconds equals 9 minutes 59 seconds, but 600 seconds equals to 9 minutes. I tried using a button to trigger the commands instead of textchanged and button did the job fine. So, I reckon, the root of the problem must be textchanged event itself. I'll be adding three examples. Screenshot images are in Turkish but you will easily get the idea.

How can I solve this, and what causes this problem? This is really mind boggling.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwTgi.jpg)

```
int second, minute, hour, minuteLeft, secondLeft;

    private void txtTime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CalculateTime();

    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    void CalculateTime()
    {
        if (txtTime.Text != "")
        {

            second = Convert.ToInt32(txtSure.Text);
            secondLeft = second % 60;
            second = second - minuteLeft;

            minute = second / 60;
            minuteLeft = minute % 60;
            minute = minute - minuteLeft;

            hour = minute / 60;


            lblMsg.Text = hour.ToString() + " hours, " + minuteLeft.ToString() + " minutes " + secondLeft.ToString() + " seconds.";
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "";
        }
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend removing this line`int second, minute, hour, minuteLeft, secondLeft;` and then declaring the variables as needed in `CalculateTime` . _There is no need for `second` etc to be fields._

Comment: @mjwills Hi, thanks for the feedback. What would be the advantage of doing so? To make the code cleaner?

Comment: Yes, to make it cleaner. And also, the compiler would have showed you the bug straight away. `var second = Convert.ToInt32(txtSure.Text);
var secondLeft = second % 60;
second = second - minuteLeft;

var minute = second / 60;
var minuteLeft = minute % 60;
minute = minute - minuteLeft;

var hour = minute / 60;` wouldn't compile - because of your bug. Which is great - the compiler (rather than stackoverflow) did the hard work for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are subtracting `minuteLeft` from the number of seconds:

```
second = second - minuteLeft;
```

That should be subtracting the secondLeft value:

```
second = second - secondLeft;
```

Comment: I cannot believe that I've missed it. Thank you! Still, how did I get it to work perfectly with a button? The code was exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider attacking the problem in a different way:

```
var durationInSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(txtTime.Text);
var duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, durationInSeconds);

var second = duration.Seconds;
var minute = duration.Minutes;
var hour = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Truncate(duration.TotalHours));
```

*`TimeSpan` is well suited to this class of problem, and will allow you to 'automatically' extract the hour, minute and second component of the duration.*

You could also consider replacing:

```
hour.ToString() + " hours, " + minuteLeft.ToString() + " minutes " + secondLeft.ToString() + " seconds.";
```

with a call to:

```
public static string ToPrettyFormat(TimeSpan timeSpan)
{
    var dayParts = new[] { GetDays(timeSpan), GetHours(timeSpan), GetMinutes(timeSpan) }
        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
        .ToArray();

    var numberOfParts = dayParts.Length;

    string result;
    if (numberOfParts < 2)
        result = dayParts.FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
    else
        result = string.Join(", ", dayParts, 0, numberOfParts - 1) + " and " + dayParts[numberOfParts - 1];

    return result.UppercaseFirst();
}
```

*Stolen from https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24995/convert-timespan-to-readable-text .*